# Projection in AR model

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, autoregressive, acf-pacf

I am currently reading the Brookwell and Davis Book and cuurently read about the PACF. On page 98 they derive the PACF for the AR(1) model 
$$
X(t)=0.9X(t-1)+Z(t)
$$
and say that the orthogonal projection of $X(1)$ on $\overline{\text{sp}}\{X(2),...,X(k)\}$ is $0.9X(2)$. How does one proof this?